# How to calculate time elapsed between non-consecutive rows?

Tags: sql, mariadb, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE useraudit(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `event` INT(1) unsigned,
    `datetime` DATETIME,
    `computer` VARCHAR(24) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
    `username` VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
    `session` VARCHAR(24) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
    `server` VARCHAR(24) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `useraudit` (`id`, `event`, `datetime`, `computer`, `username`, `session`, `server`) VALUES
(1, 0, '2020-07-24 20:21:04', 'DC1', 'testuser', '', '\\\\DC1 '),
(2, 0, '2020-07-24 20:21:04', 'DC1', 'testuser', 'Console', '\\\\DC1 '),
(3, 1, '2020-07-24 20:49:19', 'DC1', 'testuser', 'Console', '\\\\DC1 '),
(4, 1, '2020-07-24 21:19:33', 'TEST-PC-2', 'testuser', 'Console', '\\\\DC1 '),
(5, 0, '2020-07-24 21:21:35', 'TEST-PC-2', 'testuser', '', '\\\\DC1 '),
(6, 1, '2020-07-24 21:22:28', 'TEST-PC-2', 'testuser', 'Console', '\\\\DC1 '),
(7, 0, '2020-07-24 21:25:48', 'TEST-PC-2', 'testuser', '', '\\\\DC1 '),
(8, 1, '2020-07-24 21:29:16', 'TEST-PC-2', 'testuser', 'Console', '\\\\DC1 '),
(9, 1, '2020-07-24 21:29:18', 'TEST-PC-2', 'testuser', 'Console', '\\\\DC1 '),
(10, 0, '2020-07-24 21:30:06', 'TEST-PC-2', 'testuser', '', '\\\\DC1 '),
(11, 0, '2020-07-24 21:30:07', 'TEST-PC-2', 'testuser', 'Console', '\\\\DC1 '),
(12, 1, '2020-07-24 21:30:56', 'TM-PC', 'testuser', 'Console', '\\\\DC1 '),
(13, 1, '2020-07-24 21:31:07', 'TM-PC', 'testuser', 'Console', '\\\\DC1 '),
(14, 0, '2020-07-24 21:33:30', 'TM-PC', 'testuser', '', '\\\\DC1 '),
(15, 0, '2020-07-24 21:33:31', 'TM-PC', 'testuser', 'Console', '\\\\DC1 '),
(16, 1, '2020-07-25 14:32:25', 'TEST-PC-1', 'testuser', 'RDP-Tcp#7', '\\\\DC1 '),
(17, 1, '2020-07-25 14:32:25', 'TEST-PC-1', 'testuser', 'RDP-Tcp#7', '\\\\DC1 '),
(18, 0, '2020-07-25 14:32:37', 'TEST-PC-1', 'testuser', '', '\\\\DC1 '),
(19, 0, '2020-07-25 14:32:38', 'TEST-PC-1', 'testuser', 'RDP-Tcp#7', '\\\\DC1 '),
(20, 1, '2020-07-25 14:39:46', 'TEST-PC-1', 'testuser', 'RDP-Tcp#8', '\\\\DC1 '),
(21, 1, '2020-07-25 14:39:46', 'TEST-PC-1', 'testuser', 'RDP-Tcp#8', '\\\\DC1 '),
(22, 0, '2020-07-25 15:02:10', 'TEST-PC-1', 'testuser', '', '\\\\DC1 '),
(23, 0, '2020-07-25 15:02:11', 'TEST-PC-1', 'testuser', 'RDP-Tcp#8', '\\\\DC1 '),
(24, 0, '2020-07-25 15:02:28', 'DC1', 'testuser', '', '\\\\DC1 '),
(25, 0, '2020-07-25 15:02:28', 'DC1', 'testuser', 'Console', '\\\\DC1 ');
```

What I'd like to do is be able to calculate logon times - both per session and cumulatively for each user. This is a bit complicated by the fact that some events seem to generate 2 events (especially when a remote session occurs).

I'm having a difficult time approaching this; my first inclinations were to `GROUP BY datetime`, except some of these duplicate events don't occur in the same second, but the second before or after, so that won't quite work.

For the time being, I'm thinking it would just be easier to get a list of all logon sessions and their durations, by sorting by `datetime ASC` and then for each `event = 1` (which represents a logon as opposed to a logoff), search until I find the next `event = 0` for the same `computer` and `username`. Technically, these duplicate logs are FILO (first-in-last-out) but since they are within seconds of each other it doesn't really matter.

If I can query this, it wouldn't be too difficult I imagine to filter out results that have essentially an identical number of seconds; this aside, how would I approach this kind of query? I'm basically hoping for something like:

```
username | computer | logon_time           | duration`
testuser   DC1         2020-07-24 20:49:19  (seconds between 2020-07-24 20:49:19 and 2020-07-25 15:02:28)
testuser  TEST-PC-2    2020-07-24 21:19:19   2 minutes, 2 seconds
testuser  TEST-PC-2    2020-07-24 21:22:28   3 minutes, 20 seconds
testuser  TEST-PC-2    2020-07-24 21:29:16   50 seconds
testuser  TEST-PC-2    2020-07-24 21:29:18   49 seconds
testuser  TM-PC        2020-07-24 21:30:56   2 minutes, 24 seconds
etc.
```

I'm using human-friendly times here, but in actuality these times would all be durations in seconds.

(Not all rows might be used; the first two records here are 0s so can just be ignored.)

Since we kind of have to, the assumption can be made that the next logoff event for a specific user/computer after a logon event is the match for that one (in which case don't use it again for a different logon event). In other words, some of the data could be "noise" that we have to ignore, and logon/logoff pairs can't be "reused".

I started doing this in PHP, but that means I lose the ability to sort and aggregate the data, which is not ideal. Not sure if this is screaming windows in some way, but I am using MariaDB 10.1 which doesn't support them well/at all.

Comment: This is a gaps-and-island problem. Solving iy without window functions is really challenging. Any plans to upgrade to MariaDB 10.3 or higher?

Comment: @GMB Eventually hopefully, but not in the near future, unfortunately.

Comment: @GMB If that's a make-it-or-break it thing, a MariaDB 10.3 solution is better than none at all if 10.1 won't work. I can see what I can do in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the correct query to use (unless you also have different servers, then you have to expand your join conditions).

```
SELECT lon.`username`, 
       lon.`computer`, 
       lon.`session` ,
       lon.`datetime`                  AS logontime, 
       lof.`datetime`                  AS logofftime, 
       lof.`datetime` - lon.`datetime` AS duration 
FROM   `useraudit` lon 
       INNER JOIN `useraudit` lof 
               ON lon.`computer` = lof.`computer` 
                  AND lon.`username` = lof.`username` 
                  AND lon.`session` = lof.`session` 
                  AND lon.`id` < lof.`id` 
WHERE  lon.`event` = 1 
       AND lof.`event` = 0 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT lon1.id 
                       FROM   `useraudit` lon1 
                       WHERE  lon1.`event` = 1 
                          AND lon1.`computer` = lon.`computer` 
                          AND lon1.`username` = lon.`username` 
                          AND lon1.`session` = lon.`session` 
                              AND lon1.`id` < lon.`id` 
                              AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT lof1.id 
                                              FROM   `useraudit` lof1 
                                              WHERE  lof1.`event` = 0 
                                                     AND lof1.`computer` = lon.`computer` 
                                                     AND lof1.`username` = lon.`username` 
                                                     AND lof1.`session` = lon.`session` 
                                                     AND lon1.`id` < 
                                                         lof1.`id` 
                                                     AND lof1.`id` < 
                                                         lon.`id`))
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT lof2.id 
                       FROM   `useraudit` lof2 
                       WHERE  lof2.`event` = 0 
                          AND lof2.`computer` = lon.`computer` 
                          AND lof2.`username` = lon.`username` 
                          AND lof2.`session` = lon.`session` 
                              AND lon.`id` < lof2.`id` AND lof2.`id` < lof.`id`) 
             
ORDER  BY lon.`datetime`;
```

Comment: Wait, it's not correct yet, I forgot to match some fields... wait a moment...

Comment: This is great! Were you able to work out the issue from 14 minutes ago?

Comment: Well, only if the outcome is what you expect. By the way, I'm going to sleep now. It's 2:00 in the morning in the Netherlands...

Comment: If it doesn't work, it could be a good start to make something that works for you...